# Is a good idea for performance issue use ASN.1 protocol (or other bit conversion) than json+gzip?

Tags: android, json, web-services, bit-manipulation, asn.1

Suppose you have a common communication protocol between your app and webservice. This protocol never changes and has a high demand.

I was thinking, to get a better performance use ASN.1(or other in-house bit code protocol) protocolo to code all information inside Android before send to webservice.

Today, I use json encode, and after I gzip all information before send to the webservice. I have the cost of zipping and unzipping the data, more json_decode and encode for both sides.

I know that to code to ASN.1 I will have bit operations to code and decode, but generally they are really fast. And other point that I am planning to NOT zip this information, once I am using bit coding the size will be reduced naturally.

An important observation is that I want to get a better perfomance to the server side. The client performance issue is not a problem here.

Comment: how big is the average message ? Is the compression/decompression time really so high, to be a problem more than actual transmission time/mobile net latency ?

Comment: so instead of asn1 use google's [protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: Over 200 cruds per message, 1 Million users sending every 5 min. Yes It is a considerable data amount.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/beating-json-performance-with-protobuf/

Comment: `"Protobuf performs up to 6 times faster than JSON"` isnt it enough?

Comment: Yes It is, i put a bechmarch link in here

Comment: and you can use [this](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/javanano) on the client side: `JavaNano is a special code generator and runtime library designed specially for resource-restricted systems, like Android. It is very resource-friendly in both the amount of code and the runtime overhead.`

Comment: When choosing a serialisation protocol, you may want to consider things like memory requirements (zero copy, buffering), wire size vs processing overhead, ability to produce/consume large data incrementally, built-in security, human readability, library support. Typically, you got to compromise on something.